# Duda sobre las pruebas unitarias

Tags: pruebas-unitarias, unittest

Tengo claro cual es el propósito de estas, sin embargo, desde mi punto de vista no creo que exista una sola forma de realizar el test a un método en especifico, deben de existir muchas y si estoy mal, díganme por favor.

Mi duda:

Si por ejemplo tengo un método (service) que se encarga de registrar la cuenta bancaria de un cliente y para ello, dentro de ese método se necesita conectar con otra API para obtener o verificar si ese cliente existe o no para registrar la cuenta.. como punto principal, en un test, solo necesito probar que ese método (service) funcione y nada mas???

Así lo pruebe como sea.. ? Disculpen soy nuevo en esto de las pruebas unitarias. Espero me puedan resolver mis dudas. Gracias.

Comment: Se llaman pruebas unitarias porque prueban el funcionamiento de **UNA** cosa. Si en tu método realizas una llamada a una api externa, en tu prueba unitaria esa llamada se realiza contra un mock de una API, porque así controlas la respuesta de dicha api de manera 100% exacta y le indicas qué debe responder en cada test o caso de prueba. Si dejas que la llamada se realice de manera normal, ya no sería un test unitario, y de hecho, podría fallar por problemas de internet o de la otra API... estarías probando bien tu método?? No, tu método podría estar bien y fallar el test por culpa de terceros

Answer (score 2):

> [...] tengo un método (service) que se encarga de registrar la cuenta bancaria de un cliente y para ello, dentro de ese método se necesita conectar con otra API para obtener o verificar si ese cliente existe o no para registrar la cuenta.

Supongamos que tienes algo como

```
ServicioCuentas servicioCuentas; //se inyecta esta dependencia

Cuenta registrarCuenta(Cuenta nuevaCuenta) {
  if (servicioCuentas.validar(nuevaCuenta)) {
     return servicioCuentas.registrar(nuevaCuenta);
  } else {
     return null;
  }
}
```

Por tanto podrías hacer algo como crear un mock de servicioCuentas y comprobar los resultados según los valores devueltos por este servicio:

```
 ServicioCuentas mock = Mockito.mock(ServicioCuentas.class);
 Cuenta c = ... 
 when(mock.validar(any(Cuenta.class))).thenReturn(true);
 when(mock).registrar(any(Cuenta.class))).thenReturn(c);
 assertEquals(c, registrarCuenta(c));
```

En resumen: asume el control de todas las dependencias y comprueba para cada posible opción que tu método hace lo que se espera de él: si las validaciones se pasan, se llama al método correspondiente. Si no se pasan, que no se llama al método. Si alguna llamada lanza una excepción, que tu método responde como se espera (quizá no haciendo nada, o quizá relanzando la excepción o capturándola y haciendo otra cosa).